# Libvirt guest destroyed after shutdown

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, shutdown

I have created a VM withLibvirt and when I shut it down whether forcefully or with ACPI, it gets deleted. I create it:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
    <name>deneme2</name>
    <memory>2097152</memory>
    <vcpu>1</vcpu>
    <os>
        <type>hvm</type>
        <boot dev="hd" />
    </os>
    <features>
       <acpi/>
    </features>
    <on_poweroff>preserve</on_poweroff>
    <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
    <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
    <on_lockfailure>poweroff</on_lockfailure>
    <devices>
        <graphics type='vnc' port='-1'/>
        <disk type='file' device='disk'>
            <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
            <source file='/home/mustafa/buki/vms/deneme2/disk0.img'/>
            <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
        </disk>
        <disk type='file' device='disk'>
            <source file='/home/mustafa/buki/vms/deneme2/cloud-init.img'/>
            <target dev='vdb' bus="virtio"/>
        </disk>
        <interface type='network'>
            <source network='br0-bridge'/>
            <mac address='00:16:3e:5a:41:9c'/>
            <model type="virtio" />
        </interface>

    </devices>
```

However although I use on_poweroff event properly, it gets deleted immediately.

```
$ virsh dumpxml deneme2 | grep "on_poweroff"
  <on_poweroff>preserve</on_poweroff>

$ virsh shutdown deneme2 --mode acpi
Domain deneme2 is being shutdown

$ virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You created your guest with `virsh create` (or its equivalent). This creates [*transient* domains](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VM_lifecycle#Transient_guest_domains_vs_Persistent_guest_domains), which are deleted when they power off.

To create *persistent* domains, use `virsh define` instead. These remain defined after they are powered off or destroyed, and can be started again at any time.

Comment: Perhaps mention `<on_poweroff>preserve</on_poweroff>` does not do what one might assume.

Comment: You are right, I am using a libvirt go library I had used `DomainCreateXML`instead of `DomainDefineXML` , much appreciated.

@h0tw1r3 what does preserve does than?

Comment: I have no idea what `preserve` is supposed to preserve. It's not very well documented. And it's not necessary for normal operation anyway.

Comment: AFAIK `preserve` is automatically translated to `destroy` for qemu, but with other hypervisors it will save the VM resources (all it's memory, hardware state, etc). Useful for low level debugging.